# Showing special char on with jquery load

Tags: jquery, character-encoding, doctype

I'm using jquery .load() method to load a php page on my site. When I test the page to be loaded :

```
http://www.astralinternet.com/top-10-raisons.php
```

All the special french character show up properly.  But when I load this page in my script :

```
$('.BlackBox_Display').load('http://www.astralinternet.com/top-10-raisons.php', function() {
  //My code to center the DIV
});
```

All my french special char "é, è, à, ..." are not showing up properly in IE (But in Chrome yes?)

Can anyone give me a pointer as to where to look to debug my page? I'm in xhtml strict.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a character encoding problem try send a header

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15'); ?>
```

in your php file

Comment: I love you!!!!! :P I was about to break my computer and this solve my issue! Thank you! I'm been passing the last two hours on the problem!

Comment: Ok, love my answer and select it as accepted answer